# Symfony2 jQuery-File-Upload not showing his front-end input

Tags: jquery, symfony, twig, jquery-file-upload

I'm having troubles because the bundle is working -files are uploaded perfectly to the right place- but in my template the plugin shows only a file input box and all three jquery files are correctly opened... Any idea?

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="{{ oneup_uploader_endpoint('gallery') }}" multiple />
<script type="text/javascript"  src="{{ asset('bundles/site/js/file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="{{ asset('bundles/site/js/file- upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="{{ asset('bundles/site/js/file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Did you add the CSS part?

Comment: I though it should be something about css, but I'm following the developer instructions in https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/frontend_blueimp.md

Comment: Do you have any JS errors showed in the console?

Comment: no js errors, also including the css as in demo page, and nothing, just the file type input, as it is not taking the styles -because the js is taked, files are uploading-